# React router v6 useNavigate does not work with redux dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router-dom

In my `React` app, I am trying to navigate to a new page after I dispatch an `redux` action. This needs to happen on my form `onSubmit`.

The `submit` works as intended and the `redux` action is dispatched successfully, but the react router does not `navigate` to the given page after the `redux` action is dispatched. If I remove the `redux` dispatch, it navigates successfully. I'm using the `useNavigate` hook from `react-router-dom`.

My form is used as per my UI library `Mantine`. https://mantine.dev/hooks/use-form/

What is wrong here?

The `useNavigate` hook definition:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

The `onSubmit` function:

```
const handlerAddShipping = (values: any) => {


      dispatch(saveShippingAddress(values)); //if removed, navigate works.

      navigate("/payment"); //does not navigate with the previous line.


};
```

How routes are defined in my `index.tsx`

```
 <Provider store={store}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
              <Route path="/shipping" element={<Shipping />} />
              <Route path="/payment" element={<Payment />} />
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
```

The `useForm` hook from my UI library `Mantine`:

```
  const form = useForm({
    initialValues: {
      address: "",
      city: "",
      postalCode: "",
      country: "",
    },
    validationRules: {
      address: (value) => value.trim().length >= 2,
      city: (value) => value.trim().length >= 2,
      postalCode: (value) => value.trim().length >= 2,
      country: (value) => value.trim().length >= 2,
    },
    errorMessages: {
      address: "Address is not valid",
      city: "City is not valid",
      postalCode: "Postal Code is not valid",
      country: "Country is not valid",
    },
  });
```

The form:

```
<form onSubmit={form.onSubmit((values) => 
      handlerAddShipping(values))}>
      <Grid sx={{ marginTop: "2rem" }}>
        <Col span={12}>
          <TextInput
            radius="xl"
            placeholder="Your Address"
            {...form.getInputProps("address")}
            error={form.errors.address}
            label="Address"
          />
        </Col>
        <Col span={12}>
          <TextInput
            radius="xl"
            placeholder="Your City"
            {...form.getInputProps("city")}
            error={form.errors.city}
            label="City"
          />
        </Col>
        <Col span={12}>
          <TextInput
            radius="xl"
            placeholder="Your Postal Code"
            {...form.getInputProps("postalCode")}
            error={form.errors.postalCode}
            label="Postal Code"
          />
        </Col>
        <Col span={12}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Your Country"
            {...form.getInputProps("country")}
            error={form.errors.country}
            label="Country"
          />
        </Col>
        <Col span={12}>
          <Button
            type="submit">
            Continue
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Grid>
    </form>
```

React router version :
`"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1"`

Comment: Where is `handlerAddShipping` being called? Please include all relevant code in your question. Can we see that complete component? Please also check if there are any errors preventing the dispatched action from being processed in middleware/reducer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese added the form

Comment: What is `form.onSubmit((values) => handlerAddShipping(values))`? Are you using some form manager? Can we also see what `dispatch(saveShippingAddress(values));` does, the `saveShippingAddress` action creator, and asynchronous logic and/or reducer that handles it? Is the dispatched action working in isolation of the navigation event?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes. It is from my UI library. https://mantine.dev/hooks/use-form/. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// check your flows something else is happening after the navigate method, if not then try just with a return.
const handlerAddShipping = (values: any) => {
  dispatch(saveShippingAddress(values));  
  navigate("/payment");
  return;
};


// send your callback through the action and execute it there
const handlerAddShipping = (values: any) => {
  dispatch(saveShippingAddress(values, () => navigate("/payment")));
};

//if that doesnt work try this
const handlerAddShipping = (values: any) => {
  dispatch(saveShippingAddress(values));  
  setTimeout(() => navigate("/payment"), 400);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing more research, I was able to make the `navigate` work.

```
  const handlerAddShipping = (values: any) => {

    //swapped the below 2 lines.

    navigate("/payment");

    //dispatch after navigate
    dispatch(saveShippingAddress(values));

  };
```

I moved my navigate using `useNavigate` hook usage over the `redux` action `dispatch`, which gave me the intended behaviour.